# How to add an interpolating point to InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: functions, interpolation

Suppose I have an `InterpolatingFunction` object defined on $[\epsilon,1]$; let's call it `f`. What is the best way to construct a function `g` that coincides with `f` on $[\epsilon,1]$ and satisfies `g[0]==a` (`g` should be an `InterpolatingFunction`, too)? Small perturbations near $\epsilon$ are allowed.

Any generalizations are welcome as well.

Comment: I have a difficulty in choosing appropriate tags here. Is [functions] enough?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible at all unless you use *linear* interpolation.  Higher order interpolation uses more than one point to compute function values.

Comment: In fact nonlinear extensions are possible, but I've added a note that it is not very necessary to strictly reproduce f near epsilon.

Comment: What I meant when I said not sure if it's possible was that I'm not sure if Mathematica's `InterpolatingFunction` makes this technically possible.  If you are willing to accept a different type of Mathematica object (not `InterpolatingFunction`), then it is definitely possible.

Comment: I wonder which of these solutions will be able to handle the result of `Interpolation[{{{0.1}, 0.11, 0.73, 0.92}, {{0.3}, 0.91}, {{0.4}, 0.95}, {{0.6}, 0.49, 0.87}, {{0.9}, 0.95, 0.25}}]`...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When I told you that this was not possible, I was wrong.

My understanding is that you have points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ..., (x_n, y_n)$ through which you construct an interpolating function $f$.  Now you need to add another point $(x_0, y_0)$, and construct a new interpolating function $f^*$ for which it is true that $f^*(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [x_1, x_n]$.  I thought it was not possible to keep the function value unchanged in the interval $[x_1, x_n]$ when using higher value interpolation, but this is not the case.  See below:

Let's make an interpolation function from cosine values between 0.1 and 1.0:

```
ifun = Interpolation@Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, .1, 1, .1}]
```

It looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The trick is that when we add an extra point at $x=0$, we need to keep all derivatives unchanged in $x = 0.1$ up to the order of interpolation.

You can get the order of interpolation like this:

```
ifun["InterpolationOrder"]

(* ==> 3 *)
```

Let's get the derivative values in the first point:

```
derivs = Table[
  Derivative[i][ifun][ifun["Grid"][[1, 1]]], 
  {i, 0, First@ifun["InterpolationOrder"] - 1}]

(* ==> {0.995004, -0.0995897, -1.00396} *)
```

And inject them back into the function, while adding a new value $f(0) = 2$:

```
ifun2 = Interpolation@Join[
          {{{0}, 2},
           {ifun["Grid"][[1]], Sequence @@ derivs}},
          Rest@Thread[{ifun["Grid"], ifun["ValuesOnGrid"]}]
        ]
```

Notice that the function is unchanged for all values greater than 0.1:

```
Plot[{ifun2[x], ifun[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you are wondering where I got this special API to `InterpolatingFunction` where we do things like `ifun["Grid"]`: I simply looked into the `` DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` `` package that the other answers used.

Comment: Is the purpose of taking one less than the order of the interpolation function because the point directly prior to the point we wish to add will necessarily have to change its final derivative to be continuous with the new point?

Answer (score 11):

You will have to make assumptions for the derivatives of your function at zero, unless your interpolating order is 1 (which is what @Szabolcs said in the comments).  There is a package caled `` DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` ``, which *should* help (it does, but is not enough). The way to really reconstruct your data is outlined in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711677/how-to-extract-all-the-data-from-interpolatingfunction-for-creating-identical-on) question. I will reproduce the main function from that answer here (see the answer for details):

```
Clear[reconstructInterpolatingFunction];
reconstructInterpolatingFunction[intf_InterpolatingFunction] :=
   With[{data = intf[[4, 3]], 
      step = Subtract @@ Reverse[ Take[intf[[4, 2]], 2]],
      order = 
          Developer`FromPackedArray@
              InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[intf],
      grid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[intf]
      },
     Interpolation[
         MapThread[Prepend, {Partition[data, step], grid}], 
         InterpolationOrder -> order
     ]
   ];
```

You will have to modify it, by changing `MapThread[Prepend, {Partition[data, step], grid}]` to `Prepend[MapThread[Prepend, {Partition[data, step], grid}],{a,f'[0],...}]`, where `f'[0]` is the value of first derivative of `f` at zero, etc.

Comment: yes, yours is more complete as it more accurately reconstructs the original interpolation function in all details. I'll delete my answer as this is better.

Comment: @acl Why don't you undelete your answer, since it is simpler, and the procedure is anyways rather ad hoc, unless values for derivatives at zero are known precisely. You could just make a remark on the limitations.

Comment: Ahhh ... I just notice you posted the same thing I did a full 30 minutes before ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I had an advantage: I did it before, and merely reproduced part of my past answer :). You also made a nice visual analysis which I did not. The point that I made but you did not however is that `InterpolatingFunction` object *does* keep all the values for derivatives, so there is no need to compute them. The price to pay is that I rely on undocumented internal details of the format in which `InterpolatingFunction` keeps its data. This would be unnecessary if the designers of the ``InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` `` API did not overlook that info for derivatives is not accessible.

Comment: Have a look at intf["Methods"]; Furthermore, if the input to the function specifies g[a] and g'[a] you could get the derivatives of intf, by using D[intf[x],x] and then extract the data from that interpolation function append the g'[a] and re-interpolate.

Comment: @ruebenko I looked, and saw nothing to extract data say for derivative for order `n` (may be I missed it?). Your second suggestion should work, and did not cross my mind. Still, I think that since the data is stored in the `InterpolatingFunction` directly, it shoud have been made available through a direct accessor function.

Comment: @ruebenko Interesting!  Do you know how "MethodInformation" works?  It tells me I'm calling it with 0 parameters while 1 is expected, but I'm not even sure how to pass parameters to a "method"

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, you could use D[intf[x],{x,n}] for the n-th derivative.

Comment: @ruebenko Yes, thanks, I got that part.

Comment: @Szabolcs, if["MethodInformation"["ValuesOnGrid"]] is your friend. But this will most likely be replaced in a future version with a better interface.